# Как вывести значение value в данном случаи?

Tags: php, mysql

Например, если нам нужна функция выборки с БД для страницы контактов, то ее можно сделать так:

```
function the_name_contact($param) {
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
      if ($param == "title") {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
            echo $row['name'];
            }
      }
      elseif ($param == "email") {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
            echo $row['email'];
            }
      }
      elseif ($param == "address") {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
            echo $row['address'];
            }
      }
    };
```

функция ничего не возвращает. У нее есть параметр $param и если мне нужно отобразить определенное поле с БД в атрибуте value (это нужно для админки что бы было видно значение поля) или просто вывести в любой тег на сайте в нужном месте, то я могу записать так `<?php the_name_contact('email'); ?>` вызвать функцию с параметром email который равен полю email в БД.
А если мне нужно, например, нужна функция выборки С БД страницы со слайдером магазинов, где есть название и описание. Здесь уже немного иная структура:

```
$main_menu = get_stores();

  function get_stores() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $count++; 
      $res_array[$count] = $row;
    }
    return $res_array;
  }
```

Этот скрипт я делал по примеру и здесь мне немного не понятно. Есть функция `get_stores()` в которой в цикле идет выборка. и здесь мы не объявляем функцию, а возвращаем значение, почему так? И не понятно зачем `$count++`; , в предыдущем скрипте инкремента не было, зачем он здесь? Это приравнение тоже не понятно `$res_array[$count] = $row;`
С этим закончили, теперь нужно в цикле вывести слайды, делаю я это через foreach.

```
<?php foreach ($our_stores as $stores): ?>
   <a href="portfolio.php?type=stores&id=<?=$stores['id'] ?>"><h3 class="title"><?= $stores['title']?></h3></a>
   <p class="desc">
   <?= $stores['address']?>
   </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Здесь на сайт все выводится с помощью переменной `<?= $stores['title']?>` которая массив и у нее индекс это поле с БД, здесь все хорошо. Но у меня есть форма в админке которая добавляет, редактирует и удаляет слайды. И проблема в том что я никак не могу вывести в поле value на странице редактирования слайда значение, типа как `<?= $stores['title']?>` но оно работает только в этом цикле foreach. А в админке foreach мне не нужен. Голову уже сломал, не могу понять как вывести value на странице редактирования слайда?
В первом примере с функцией `the_name_contact()`  и параметром $param все просто, а здесь так не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.

> здесь мы не объявляем функцию, а возвращаем значение, почему так

На самом деле функцию объявили вот - function get_stores()

> И не понятно зачем $count++; , в предыдущем скрипте инкремента не было, зачем он здесь

В предыдщем примере вы выводили в цикле используя echo, а в этой функции вы сохраняете данные в массив. Для этого $count сначала надо присвоить 0, а затем вы увеличиваете индекс ($count), чтобы не перезаписывать предыдущие значения. вы можете убрать count и записывать просто в массив $res_array[] = $row; тогда значения будут добавляться в конец массива

> И проблема в том что я никак не могу вывести в поле value на странице редактирования слайда значение, типа как

$stores это один элемент из массива foreach в вашем примере. Если вы не можете найти какую то переменную у себя, то сделайте var_dump(переменная)
посмотрите какая структура массива или объекта, и достаньте значение.

В функцию добавил вам комментариев:

```
$main_menu = get_stores(); // вызов функции

function get_stores() { // определние функции
   $res_array = [];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // получение данных из базы
     $res_array[] = $row; // добавление данных в массив
   }
   return $res_array; // возвращение массива с данными
}
```